# Importing from sibling directory

Tags: python, import

I have searched this question over stackoverflow but can't find an answer that fixes this. I am trying to learn how to do proper imports with python.

I am using Python 3.8.2 and I have the following simple directory setup.

```
main_folder\
    folder1\
        myclass.py
    folder2\
        testclass2.py
    testclass1.py
```

Both testclass1.py and testclass2.py have this inside:

```
from folder1.myclass import Myclass
```

This works fine for testclass1.py, but when I run in testclass2.py it gives me an error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'

Even though I had read Python no longer requires this, I inserted an `__init__.py` file into folder1. This generated the same error. I then tried following directions for the init file in [this article](https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html) but there was no improvement. I also tried using relative paths versus absolute paths for import, but no success.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From `testclass2.py` the import should be like this:

```py
from ..folder1.myclass import Myclass
```

Comment: I try this and the result is this error: 

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: You should add __init__.py files to each of directories including main_folder

Comment: Thanks. But no difference. Also, its my understanding that init is no longer needed as of a certain version of python.